# Multivariate Linear Regression Cost Too High

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression, gradient-descent, non-linear-regression

I was working on price prediction with the data set provided in [this](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/autos/) link, the `imports-85.data`.

With `horsepower`, `curb-weight`, `engine-size` and `highway-mpg`, I tried to normalize (due to the high cost) and run the gradient descent algorithm by implementing the following:

**Initialization**

```
data = df[attrs]
m = len(data) # m-training examples
f = len(attrs) # n-features
X = np.hstack((np.ones(shape=(m,1)),np.array(data)))
T = np.zeros(f + 1) # Coefficients of x(0),x(1),...x(n)
norm_price = df.price / 1000
Y = np.array(norm_price)

# Normalization
data['curb-weight'] = (data['curb-weight'] * 0.453592) / 1000    # To kg (e-1000)
data['highway-mpg'] = data['highway-mpg'] * 0.425144    # To km per litre (kml)
data['engine-size'] = data['engine-size'] / 100     # To e-100
data['horsepower'] = data['horsepower'] / 100   # To e-100

col_rename = {
    'curb-weight':'curb-weight-kg(e-1000)',
    'highway-mpg':'highway-kml',
    'engine-size':'engine-size(e-100)',
    'horsepower':'horsepower(e-100)'
}
data.rename(columns=col_rename,inplace=True)
```

**Cost calculation**

```
def calculateCost():
    global m,T,X
    hypot = (X.dot(T) - Y).transpose().dot(X.dot(T) - Y)
    return hypot / (2 * m)
```

**Gradient descent**

```
def gradDescent(threshold,iter = 10000,alpha = 3e-8):
    global T,X,Y,m
    i = 0
    cost = calculateCost()
    cost_hist = [cost]
    while i < iter:
        T = T - (alpha / m) * X.transpose().dot(X.dot(T) - Y)
        cost = calculateCost()
        cost_hist.append(cost)
        i += 1
        if cost <= threshold:
            return cost_hist
```

I ran the gradient descent with this implementation:
[Batch Gradient Descent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VuxXQ.jpg)

Without normalization, the cost would be `118634960.460199`.
With normalization, the cost would be `118.634960460199`

**As a result, I have a few questions:**

1. Is my normalization technique correct?
2. After normalization, the cost would be different. How do I set the threshold for the cost after normalization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may be misunderstanding 'normalization' in the context of machine learning. From my interpretation of your code your 'normalization' section is doing unit conversions. Prior to gradient decent it is common to apply a max-min scaling or a standard scaling, see the [scikit learn user guide](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#preprocessing-scaler). These techniques create features with a consistent scale range, so that changes in a single feature do not completely dominate the loss function. [This question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/48360/is-standardization-needed-before-fitting-logistic-regression) and [this blog post](https://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_about_feature_scaling.html) have a longer discussion.

Comment: Oh I see. By the way, what do you mean by distribution?

Comment: Actually 'distribution' is not the best word to describe what I mean here. The shape of the distributions of the individual features will not become uniform due to these transforms, but what is important is their scale will become similar. I have edited my answer to update this and included a link to a longer discussion on the topic.